# Is a finitely generated metrizable group discrete?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups, finitely-generated, locally-compact-groups

The question is in the title. A countable locally compact Hausdorff group is discrete, so saying that a finitely generated metrizable group is locally compact would be enough.

What if the group is a subgroup of a compact metrizable group? An open or closed subspace of a compact Hausdorff space is locally compact, but here there is no hypothesis on opennes or closure.

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}$ with the $p$-adic metric ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *$p$-adic topology* on $\mathbb{Z}$, having as a basis of neighborhoods the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}$ of the form $p^n\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ a prime) is metrizable and non discrete. The completion is the group (or ring) of $p$-adic integers, which is compact and metrizable.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Consider for instance the subgroup of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ generated $a + \mathbb{Z}$ where $a$ is irrational, with the natural metric inherited from $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

It is true though that every countable *completely* metrizable topological group is discrete, which follows from the more general fact that every countable (edit) homogeneous (/edit) complete metric space is discrete.

Comment: Obviously **not** every countable complete metric space is discrete! However, every countable complete metric space has an isolated point (Baire). Hence if its self-homeomorphism group acts transitively (which holds for topological groups) it has to be discrete.

Comment: Sorry yes, I meant to say 'homogeneous' in there.